# What does "administering his favourite blow to the desk" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following line is from the Charles Dickens' novel, "Nicholas Nickleby":

> "Each boy keep his place", said Squeers, administering his favourite blow to the desk, and regarding with satisfaction the universal start which it never failed to occasion. "Nickleby! To your desk, sir."

What does "administering his favourite blow to the desk" mean here?

Answer (score 2):

It means that Squeers banged the desk in the way he liked doing, and the noise startled the boys as it always did.

(start - noun, meaning a sudden involuntary movement
“he awoke with a start”)
https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/start

Comment: It could just mean that Mr Squeers was very fond of banging the desk (that the blow was the favourite thing, rather than the manner of striking it).